# "Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined" - but it is

Tags: jquery

I've ready some similar questions and have verified that jquery is the first script included...

```
// this test confirms that jquery is defined
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert('jquery not defined');    
}
// (this is being alerted)
else { alert( 'jquery is defined'); }

// this is what I want to achieve (to begin with)
jquery("#free-signup").css( 'display', 'none' );
```

and jquery does seem to be defined... what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. You should use correct object name:

```
// v
  jQuery("#free-signup").css( 'display', 'none' );
```

or the shortcut:

```
$("#free-signup").css( 'display', 'none' );
```